# Converting text to smartart using Powerpoint addin

Tags: c#, vba, powerpoint, office-interop

I am developing Powerpoint AddIn , which will select text and then convert to smartart.

I have textRange which I want to convert to SmartArt. Is there any function provided for Addins which supports "Convert Text To SmartArt" Feature of PowerPoint.

Please help

Thanks,
Kailas

Answer (score 0):

You want to work with the parent shape, not the textrange.

Assuming a reference to the shape in oSh:

```
Call oSh.ConvertTextToSmartArt(Application.SmartArtLayouts(x))
```

where X represents the index of the SmartArt layout you want to convert to.

This will give you some idea of which layout is which:

```
Sub ListSmartArtLayouts()

Dim x as Long

With Application.SmartArtLayouts
For x = 1 to .Count
Debug.Print .Item(x).Name
Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Shape may have unrelated text as well. I would like to select textRange and convert selected text to SmartArt.

Comment: There's no method for that.  Copy the shape, delete the text you don't want and then convert it to smartart.

Comment: hmm.. looks like that is the only way I have :(